# How to derive probability mass function from cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

For $X, Y$ discrete, could you please show me how to derive
$P(X = x, Y = y)$ from the cumulative distribution function $F_{XY}(x,y) = P(X <= x, Y <= y) $ ?

Moreover, why is this derivation more difficult than finding density function from the cumulative distribution function of 2 continous random variables ? I think it is due to the fact that we just need to take partial derivative, right ?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2418723/321264

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the event $\{X=x,Y=y\}$ in terms of inequalities.

Start from the event $\{X\leq x,Y\leq y\}$. This is obviously a larger event than you want; what is the extra?

One bad case, for instance, is $\{X\leq x, Y<y\}$; assuming we're thinking these variables are integer-valued, you can rewrite $Y<y$ as $Y\leq y-1$. Thus $\{X\leq x, Y<y\}=\{X\leq x, Y\leq y-1\}$.

Continuing on in this way, you can identify the event $\{X=x, Y=y\}$ as $\{X\leq x, Y\leq y\}$ less a collection of disjoint "bad" subsets that can be written in terms of $F$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggest, I have done it! So, does it mean that to go from CDF to pmf of discrete random variables, we need $2^m$ calculations, whereas to calculate the probability density function of continous random variables, all we need to do is to partially differentiate then plug in the value, right ? could you please confirm if i am right or not ? thank you very much for your help!

Comment: They are analogous -- for instance, comparing $\{X\leq x, Y\leq y\}$ and $\{X\leq x, Y\leq y-1\}$  -- or, rather, $F_{XY}(x,y)$ and $F_{XY}(x,y-1)$, looks an awful lot like $\frac{F_{XY}(x,y)-F_{XY}(x,y-1)}{1}$.  This difference operator is a discrete analog to the partial derivative.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It is much clearer for me.

Comment: However, in fact, what I care about is the computational time in the case discrete and continuous. Could you please explain the reason why it takes much much more calculation to derive the pmf in comparison to the pdf, when in fact they are analogous ?

Comment: It only seems like less computation to compute the PDF if you ignore the actual computation of the limits that is happening.  The fact that well-behaved functions have simple, symbolically-computable derivatives hides the fact that you're actually doing all the same arithmetic (but in more generality) AND limits.